# Search field other than value field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete widget that is displaying items with custom data.

They all have a `value`, and `description`.
Currently the `value` is inserted into the textbox when an item is clicked and the `value` of an item is what is searched

What I'd like to do is have the filter use both the `value` and the `description` when filtering items to display, but keep only the `value` being inserted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Without knowing exactly which auto-complete plugin you're using, my best guess is that you'd have to modify the function it's using to filter out its list of items. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: We need to see what kind of data you're working with. Please post some code, such as your call to the `autocomplete` widget and your `source` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the autocompleter an array of objects with `value` and `label` (rather than `description`) properties, it will do the filtering for you, but only on the `label` (not the `value`).

If you specify a function for the [`source` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source), you're expected to do the filtering yourself. You receive a `request` argument (an object with a `term` property) and a `response` argument (a function to call back with the results). You then return relevant results yourself, using any kind of search you like (e.g., you can search both `value` and `description` in your code).

E.g., loosely:

```
$("some selector").autocomplete({
    // ...other options...
    source: function(request, response) {
        var matches = [];
        /* ...search for matches in your data using `request.term`,
           add them to `matches`...
        */
        response(matches);
    }
});
```

The array you return can be just strings, or it can be objects with `value` and `label` properties. The `label` will be shown, the `value` will be used when selected.

So for example, here's one using a (short) list of airports, where when you type it checks both the `value` (the airport code) and the `description` (the airport name): [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/iwahoc) | [source](http://jsbin.com/iwahoc/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var data = [
    {value: "ORD", description: "Chicago O'Hare"},
    {value: "LHR", description: "London Heathrow"},
    {value: "SFO", description: "San Francisco International"}
  ];

  $("#theInput").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var capterm = request.term.toUpperCase();
      var matches = $.map(data, function(entry) {
        if (entry.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(capterm) !== -1 ||
            entry.description.toUpperCase().indexOf(capterm) !== -1) {
          return {
            value: entry.value,
            label: entry.value + " - " + entry.description
          };
        }
      });
      response(matches);
    }
  });
});
```

So typing "or" or "chic" will show you "ORD - Chicago O'Hare", and selecting it will put "ORD" in the field. Typing "san" or "sfo" will show you "SFO - San Francisco International" and selecting it will put "SFO" in the field.

Comment: doesn't `source` simply provide the array of strings to search on, not the array of strings that match the query?

Comment: @jackwanders: If you supply an array for source, the autocompleter does the filtering for you. If you supply a function or a URL, you are expected to do the filtering yourself, the autocompleter won't do any. See the ["Overview"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) part of the autocompleter documentation, which just barely mentions this, almost in passing -- and then only because I raised a ticket months back to get them to add it. :-) jQuery UI is great. The documentation (for anything but theming) is not so great.